# Accessing sites from Python

Tags: python, token, python-requests

I am trying to access a site from python, which requires credentials, and download files from it.

I tried using below code to access a site.

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

a = requests.get("https://url",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domian\\username','password'))
print(a.status_code)
print(a.content)
```

1. The site actually requires security token to login but I don't know
   where to provide the security token in above code.
2. Without security code, I get status code as "**200**" which is for
   successful operation.

*Can someone help me to input security_token to access the site and understand why I get "200" as status_code while I am not providing correct credentials?*

Thanks

Comment: Is the site using HTTP authentication or some sort of home-baked authentication mechanism working on the browser? What do you get as the body of the response? A page telling that authentication is needed?

Comment: You may want to give the site URL: it may help to determine how to give it the required security token.
Viz. http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @juhist - I get HTML tags of the page as response. The URL is client-specific that I cannot share here.